# Odd Database Design, Need Guidance

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I am probably thinking about this wrong but here goes.

A computer starts spitting out a gazillion random numbers between 11111111111111111111 and 99999999999999999999, in a linear row:

- Sometimes the computer adds a number to one end of the line.
- Sometimes the computer adds a number to the other end of the line.
- Each number has a number that comes, or will come, before.
- Each number has a number that comes, or will come, after.
- Not all numbers are unique, many, but not most, are repeated.
- The computer never stops spitting out numbers.

As I record all of these numbers, I need to be able to make an educated guess, at any given time:

- If this is the second time I have seen a number I must know what number preceded it in line last time.
- If it has appeared more than two times, I must know the probability/frequency of numbers preceding it.
- If this is the second time I have seen a number, I must also know what number came after it in line last time.
- If it has appeared more than two times, I must know the probability/frequency of numbers coming after it.

---

How the heck do I structure the tables in a MySQL database to store all these numbers?  Which engine do I use and why?  How do I formulate my queries?  I need to know fast, but capacity is also important because when will the thing stop spitting them out?

My ill-conceived plan:

2 Tables:

```
1. Unique ID/#
2. #/ID/#
```

My thoughts:

Unique ID's are almost always going to be shorter than the number = faster match.
Numbers repeat = fewer ID rows = faster match initially.

```
Select * in table2 where id=(select id in table1 where #=?)
```

OR:

3 Tables:

```
1. Unique ID/#
2. #/ID
3. ID/#
```

My thoughts:

If I only need left/before, or only need after/right, im shrinking the size of the second query.

```
SELECT # IN table2(or 3) WHERE id=(SELECT id IN table1 WHERE #=?)
```

OR

1 Table:

```
1. #/#/#
```

Thoughts:

Less queries = less time.

```
SELECT * IN table WHERE col2=#.
```

I'm lost.... :(  Each number has four attributes, that which comes before+frequency and that which comes after+frequency.

Would I be better off thinking of it in that way?  If I store and increment frequency in the table, I do away with repetition and thus speed up my queries?  I was initially thinking that if I store every occurrence, it would be faster to figure the frequency programmatically.......

Such simple data, but I just don't have the knowledge of how databases function to know which is more efficient.

---

In light of a recent comment, I would like to add a bit of information about the actual problem:  I have a string of indefinite length.  I am trying to store a Markov chain frequency table of the various characters, or chunks of characters, in this string.

Given any point in the string I need to know the probability of the next state, and the probability of the previous state.

I am anticipating user input, based on a corpus of text and past user input.  A major difference compared to other applications I have seen is that I am going farther down the chain, more states, at a given time and I need the frequency data to provide multiple possibilities.

I hope that clarifies the picture a lot more.  I didn't want to get into the nitty gritty of the problem, because in the past I have created questions that are not specific enough to get a specific answer.

---

This seems maybe a bit better.  My primary question with this solution is: Would providing the "key" (first few characters of the state) increase the speed of the system?  i.e query for state_key, then query only the results of that query for the full state?

```
Table 1:
name: state
col1:state_id - unique, auto incrementing
col2:state_key - the first X characters of the state
col3:state - fixed length string or state

Table 2:
name: occurence
col1:state_id_left - non unique key from table 1
col2:state_id_right - non unique key from table 1
col3:frequency - int, incremented every time the two states occur next to each other.

QUERY TO FIND PREVIOUS STATES:
SELECT * IN occurence WHERE state_id_right=(SELECT state_id IN state WHERE state_key=? AND state=?)

QUERY TO FIND NEXT STATES:
SELECT * IN occurence WHERE state_id_left=(SELECT state_id IN state WHERE state_key=? AND state=?)
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/161666)?

Comment: What is '#' in your tables?

Comment: @Catcall, Intersting, I haven't been here long enough to have taken a look at the XY page.  I will add to the problem to clarify.

Comment: @Tyron, A column/field holding the 20 digit number.

Comment: I'm still trying to understand what you are doing and also the specific problem you are running into, but wouldn't you need to store all "strings" so you can go back and look for it's neighboring states for future re-occurrences?

Comment: @andreshernandez, Without some kind of reduction, that was what I was assuming also.  They either all need to be stored, or if a duplicate already exists and frequency column needs to be incremented.

Comment: working on an answer... do you have an idea of what's the number of possible states?

Comment: The example above it 20 characters long.  Just throwing a number out, but at 20 characters that is somewhere between 348678440100000000000000000000 to 8.8817841970012523233890533447266e+84 states...... Quite unrealistic.  Maybe 500,000 states done a different way, by 'word'.

Comment: @andreshernandez, larger chunk = more states = more accurate.  So the short answer is, as many as possible?

Comment: but what are the characters? just numbers or any alphanumeric character? is it case insensitive? ... this may not impact much of the solution except for the type of fields you can use.

Comment: never mind my prev. question. It's supposed to be just numbers, right?

Comment: @andreshernandex, For simplicity, in the example I used numbers.  The actual string is alpha-numeric as well as a limited amount of punctuation.

Comment: @andreshernandex, thus it has to go into a str type column.  fixed-length is always better when it needs to be queried against, isnt it?  Even if it has to be padded?

Comment: It seems to me that this isn't just about an odd database design.  It's about an odd database problem.  There's nothing wrong with trying to solve an odd problem.  But maybe, when you do, you have to expect an odd design to be suitable.

Comment: @WalterMitty, such an accurate comment.  Which odd design is suitable though....?

Comment: @SamanthaP Correct. A fixed length varchar is better suited. Add an index to the state column and drop the state_id from my example. I'm not sure you'll need to do any padding. I thought that wouldn't be an issue for MySQL to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Markov Chains but here is an attempt to answer the question. Note: To simplify things, let's call each string of numbers a 'state'.

First of all I imagine a table like this

```
Table states:
order : integer autonumeric (add an index here)
state_id : integer (add an index here)
state : varchar (?)
```

order: just use a sequential number (1,2,3,...,n) this will make it easy to search for the previous or next state.

state_id: a unique number associated to the state. As an example, you can use the number 1 to represent the state '1111111111...1' (whatever the length of the sequence is). What's important is that a reoccurrence of a state needs to use the same state_id that was used before. You may be able to formulate the state_id based on the string (maybe substracting a number). Of course a state_id only makes sense if the number of possible states fits in a MySQL int field.

state: that is the string of numbers '11111111...1' to '99999999...9' ... I'm guessing this can only be stored as a string but if it fits in an integer/number column you should try it as it may well be that you don't need the state_id

The point of state_id is that searching number is quicker than searching texts, but there will always be trade-offs when it comes to performance ... profile and identify your bottlenecks to make better design decisions.

So, how do you look for a previous occurrence of the state S_i ?

"SELECT order, state_id, state FROM states WHERE state_id = " and then attach get_state_id(S_i) where get_state_id ideally uses a formula to generate a unique id for the state.

Now, with order - 1 or order + 1 you can access the neighboring states issuing an additional query.

Next we need to track the frequency of different occurrences. You can do that in a different table that could look like this:

```
Table state_frequencies:
state_id integer (indexed)
occurrences integer
```

And only add records as you get the numbers.

Finally, you can have tables to track frequency for the neighboring states:

```
Table prev_state_frequencies (next_state_frequencies is the same):
state_id: integer (indexed)
prev_state_id: integer (indexed)
occurrences: integer
```

You will be able to infer probabilities (i guess this is what you are trying to do) by looking at the number of occurrences of a state (in state_frequencies) vs the number of occurrences of it's predecessor state (in prev_state_frequencies).

I'm not sure if I got your problem right but if this makes sense I'm guessing I have.

Hope it helps,
AH

Comment: For what is worth: A 20 digit number will not fit in an unsigned BIGINT but a 19 digit number will. If that is important then you'll need use the varchar(20) field for searches and probably add an index to it.

Comment: Interesting, I like that you've combined prev and next together. if your looking for next, you pull the id of prev, if your looking prev you would pull the id of the other.  Doesn't this double the number of rows though?  Would queries run faster if you bi-furicated these into two tables?

Comment: Actually, on second thought. a state is a state.  As you recorded it would increase the number of recorded states, but in the long run the max possible states wouldn't change......

Comment: I think you are able to combine prev_state_frequencies and next_state_frequencies into one table with a flag: 0 for prev, 1 for next

Comment: I didn't get the "state is a state" comment :(

Comment: Just meant that each chunk of data is a "state in the chain".  If two "states" are stored that are next to each other, then you could go either direction just by querying the appropriate column, and then fetching the opposite column.

Comment: I don't think an autonumeric "order" will work here.  The computer adds numbers (strings) to each end of the "line".

Comment: @Catcall: The machine is generating different states S_1, S_2, ... , S_i, ... The "order" column represents that i. Would that make sense?

Comment: It makes *logical* sense, but it doesn't match the description of the problem from @SamanthaP.

Comment: Hmmm... Let's imagine a state S_k occurs for a second time. I understood there is a need to go back and look for the first occurrence of S_k and look at the neighboring states of that occurrence. The order column would let me go back/forward 1 state from the previous occurrences.

Comment: Yes, it seems to me that there needs to be either at least two columns with adjacent states in them, or one column with an ordered key.  Although Catcall is right, there is no need to know which end of the line a number was added at - as long as we have information on what the adjacent numbers are, the position is not needed...

Comment: I took a deeper look at your answer.  Why is a table (state_frequencies) kept with state frequency independent of neighboring states?  I don't understand how this data would help me roll a probability of an adjacent state.  If a state has never been adjacent to the searched state, then it should never come come up in the probability query, even if it is by far the most common state appearing.  Only the context of being adjacent is important.

Comment: Also, would there be an improvement in speed, if it was stored in 2 tables? See edited question to read what I mean.  It would be an extra query, but it would also limit the second and third query to relatively simple single column queries, as all actually states would be stored with an ID.

Comment: Or better yet, add a third column to the state table, the first X characters of the string.  It would increase the size of the table, but it would also mean shrinking the where statement down to only matching three characters before it has to match the full string.... would that make any sense at all?

Comment: @SamanthaP Very interesting idea about using the first few characters. You could also use a check-sum or some sort of function that hashes into the 20-byte long string into an integer. Only then match the full string. You are also right that you don't need the state_frequencies table. A neighboring_states table would do. Let me have a look at your answer and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the Markov Chain is finite, so first I would start by defining the limit of the chain (i.e. 26 characters with x number of spaces to fill) then you can calculate the total number of possible combinations. to determine the probability of a certain arrangement of characters the math if I remember correctly is:

x = ((C)(C))(P)

 
where

 
C = the number of possible characters and

 
P = the total potential outcomes.

this is a ton of data to store and creating procedures to filter through the data could turn out to be a seemingly endless task.

->
if you are using an auto incremented id in your table you could query the table and use preg_match to test the new result against the previous results then insert the number of total matches with the new result into the table, this would also allow you to query the preceding results to see what came before it this should give you a general idea of the pattern within the results as well as a general base for statistical relevance and new algorithm generation

Comment: I like it.  However, depending on how large of segments the string is broken into, the possibilities are.... well, let's put it this way - too many.  If you break it by character, that is 500-1500 combinations per two character chunk.  The upside is that the majority of these won't actually occur, also some will be so uncommon that when database size becomes a problem they can probably be dropped.  Just a thought.

Comment: that is true that's why one would have to be very careful when setting the limits of the chain unfortunately while you can get a sense of the outcome with a smaller chain there are some major changes as the chain grows that effects the resulting data overall